# Android: Setting a Variable to a spinner item for later use

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

So I am trying to Work on a tutorial to learn how to code in C# for mobile applications. I have been working on a tutorial that was originally inteded for Windows Forms and I have been trying to format the code into an android version so I can test it on my phone.
What I am currently having issues with is grabbing a value from a spinner and using it later. What I would like to do is grab a "weapon" from a spinner, and then use that weapon to do damage to a monster.
The original code looked like this for Windows Forms:

```
 private void btnUseWeapon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the currently selected weapon from the cboWeapons ComboBox
            Weapon currentWeapon = (Weapon)cboWeapons.SelectedItem;

            // Determine the amount of damage to do to the monster
            int damageToMonster = RandomNumberGenerator.NumberBetween(currentWeapon.MinimumDamage, currentWeapon.MaximumDamage);

            // Apply the damage to the monster's CurrentHitPoints
            _currentMonster.CurrentHitPoints -= damageToMonster;

            // Display message
            rtbMessages.Text += "You hit the " + _currentMonster.Name + " for " + damageToMonster.ToString() + " points." + Environment.NewLine;

            // Check if the monster is dead
            if(_currentMonster.CurrentHitPoints <= 0)
            {
                // Monster is dead
                rtbMessages.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                rtbMessages.Text += "You defeated the " + _currentMonster.Name + Environment.NewLine;

                // Give player experience points for killing the monster
                _player.ExperiencePoints += _currentMonster.RewardExperiencePoints;
                rtbMessages.Text += "You receive " + _currentMonster.RewardExperiencePoints.ToString() + " experience points" + Environment.NewLine;

                // Give player gold for killing the monster 
                _player.Gold += _currentMonster.RewardGold;
                rtbMessages.Text += "You receive " + _currentMonster.RewardGold.ToString() + " gold" + Environment.NewLine;

                // Get random loot items from the monster
                List<InventoryItem> lootedItems = new List<InventoryItem>();

                // Add items to the lootedItems list, comparing a random number to the drop percentage
                foreach(LootItem lootItem in _currentMonster.LootTable)
                {
                    if(RandomNumberGenerator.NumberBetween(1, 100) <= lootItem.DropPercentage)
                    {
                        lootedItems.Add(new InventoryItem(lootItem.Details, 1));
                    }
                }

                // If no items were randomly selected, then add the default loot item(s).
                if(lootedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    foreach(LootItem lootItem in _currentMonster.LootTable)
                    {
                        if(lootItem.IsDefaultItem)
                        {
                            lootedItems.Add(new InventoryItem(lootItem.Details, 1));
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Add the looted items to the player's inventory
                foreach(InventoryItem inventoryItem in lootedItems)
                {
                    _player.AddItemToInventory(inventoryItem.Details);

                    if(inventoryItem.Quantity == 1)
                    {
                        rtbMessages.Text += "You loot " + inventoryItem.Quantity.ToString() + " " + inventoryItem.Details.Name +Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rtbMessages.Text += "You loot " + inventoryItem.Quantity.ToString() + " " + inventoryItem.Details.NamePlural + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }

                // Refresh player information and inventory controls
                lblHitPoints.Text = _player.CurrentHitPoints.ToString();
                lblGold.Text = _player.Gold.ToString();
                lblExperience.Text = _player.ExperiencePoints.ToString();
                lblLevel.Text = _player.Level.ToString();

                UpdateInventoryListInUI();
                UpdateWeaponListInUI();
                UpdatePotionListInUI();

                // Add a blank line to the messages box, just for appearance.
                rtbMessages.Text += Environment.NewLine;

                // Move player to current location (to heal player and create a new monster to fight)
                MoveTo(_player.CurrentLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                // Monster is still alive

                // Determine the amount of damage the monster does to the player
                int damageToPlayer = RandomNumberGenerator.NumberBetween(0, _currentMonster.MaximumDamage);

                // Display message
                rtbMessages.Text += "The " + _currentMonster.Name + " did " + damageToPlayer.ToString() + " points of damage." + Environment.NewLine;

                // Subtract damage from player
                _player.CurrentHitPoints -= damageToPlayer;

                // Refresh player data in UI
                lblHitPoints.Text = _player.CurrentHitPoints.ToString();

                if(_player.CurrentHitPoints <= 0)
                {
                    // Display message
                    rtbMessages.Text += "The " + _currentMonster.Name + " killed you." + Environment.NewLine;

                    // Move player to "Home"
                    MoveTo(World.LocationByID(World.LOCATION_ID_HOME));
                }
            }
        }
```

The cboWeapons in Windows Forms is a combobox.
I kept the same naming in my code but it is a spinner.

```
Spinner cboWeapons = (Spinner)FindViewById(Resource.Id.cboWeapons);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<Weapon> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Weapon>(this, 
Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, weapons);
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
cboWeapons.Adapter = adapter;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
// On selecting a spinner item
object CurrentWeapon =parent.GetItemAtPosition(position);
 Weapon currentWeapon = new CurrentWeapon();
}
```

My Weapon Class is defined in an Engine Project and I am having issues with making currentWeapon something that I can reference in the later code like the Windows Forms does.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to get selected item:

```
var TheSelectedIten = string.Format("{0}", SimpleSpinner.GetItemAtPosition(SimpleSpinner.SelectedItemPosition));
```

It works for me on a spinner list of strings.

R/
Prescott ...

Comment: That makes a var that is defined as "TheSelectedItem". How can I make that variable refer to my Weapon class?

Comment: In my application I use two parallel string lists one for the weapon, the other for information about the weapon, the var SelectedItem contains the position of the item in the list.  For example if the list contains "Spear, Ax, Bow" and the users selects "Ax", var is equal to 2.  I then use that value to index into my list of items, for example:  var weaponinfo = weaponitem[SelectedItem].ToString();  This gets me all the information on the weapon.  I'm rather new to Android apps myself and this solution worked for me.

Comment: I like that idea of using 2 lists. I am trying to use this in my code but the error I am receiving from the second set of code is that I cannot convert string to int. Looking at your first code, doesn't that define a string and not an int of 2?

Comment: You have to cast the result as an int:  For example:  int var = (int) TheSelectedItem;  Or some such.  I'm just doing this off the top of my head :).